# Dynamically Sizing UILabels

Tags: ios, uilabel

In my app I have 4 labels and I need to add them immediately below the previous label. The problem is that these labels are filled with text dynamically and I don't know the size of the label.

For example, in the code below I have 2 labels - myLabel and titleLabel. I need to paste the titleLabel immediately below myLabel, but the problem is that the height of the latter varies. And so I am not able to give the y-coordinate of titleLabel.

```
CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(22, 50, 280, 150);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[myLabel setText:finalIngredients];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[myLabel sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];


CGRect titleLabelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 25, 400, 15);
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleLabelFrame];
[titleLabel setText:title];
[self.view addSubview:titleLabel];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `myLabel.bounds.size.height` and `myLabel.frame.origin.y` to get height and starting y-coordinate for `myLabel`, respectively. To my knowledge they will change dynamically when you invoke `sizeToFit` (for instance). In your case you could simply change the line

```
CGRect titleLabelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 25, 400, 15);
```

to

```
CGRect titleLabelFrame = CGRectMake(0, myLabel.frame.origin.y + myLabel.bounds.size.height, 400, 15);
```

Comment: Hi, I get the error message - No member named 'y' in 'struct CGSize'

Comment: Sorry about that - it's supposed to be height, not y. Corrected it above.

Answer (score 1):

Calulate height dynamiclly with this:

```
 CGSize size = [finalIngredients sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]
      constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 200)
          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Here finalIngredients is your string. You just have to provide width of your label u want in place of 100.

Make calulation of label's frame dynamically depending on previous or next label

Answer (score 0):

If the text is dynamic, it stands to reason you have a function that modifies the text.

Inside that function, calculate the height of the newly modified text inside `myLabel`.  Then set the y position of `titleLabel` to be `myLabel`'s x position + `myLabel`'s newly calculated height + whatever buffer space you require between them. :)